# What versions of Windows Server support ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, windows-server

This is a very hard question to Google because there are different versions of ASP.NET out there.  What I want to know is the versions of Windows Server that support ASP.NET 2.0 (no MVC, no CORE) just the original version that was released back in 2006 (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_2.0)

Thanks!

Comment: Works on Server 2003 and anything newer.

Answer (score 1):

First, only Windows Server 2012 and above are supported now.

Second, you have to manually enable ASP.NET 3.5 there, which supports ASP.NET 2.0 web apps,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45

However, keep in mind that such ASP.NET 2.0 apps are ancient. Upgrade if you can.

Comment: Thanks @Lex Li for your response.  The link for iis8 appears to be for Windows Server 2012 only.  Do you know if it is possible to have a site written in ASP.NET 2.0 work on Windows Server 2019?

Comment: @vbguyny Essentially no change was made in later releases of Windows Server.